# Javascript condition

Tags: javascript, condição

eu comecei a estudar javascript recentemente e o codigo a seguir so está me dando a resposta errada, aonde eu errei?

Quando jogo no prompt para verficar se está certo, ele me dá "n1 é ímpar"

```
// Verifique se um número é par ou ímpar
var n1 = 4;
var sobra = n1%2;

if(sobra = 0){
    console.log("n1 é par")
}else{
    console.log("n1 é ímpar")
};
```

Comment: bom dia, evite está postando foto, é melhor posta o código mesmo, copia o código cole para uma melhor visualização, por isso alguém negativou sua pergunta.

Comment: e o erro é bem simples, você está utilizando o operador de atribuição e não de comparação, o correto séria == e não =

Comment: ai eu nao sabia apokdaposkdapo, mas brigada pela dica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, o erro é bem simples, vocês está utilizando o operador de atribuição `=`, o correto séria o operador de comparação `==`.

---

Documentação para mais informações [sobre os operadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_operators).

```
var n1 = 4;

var  sobra = n1%2;

if (sobra == 0) {
    console.log('n1 é par');
} else {
    console.log('n1 é impar');
}
```

Uma outra maneira de fazer séria assim:

```
var n1 = 4;

if ((n1 % 2) == 0) { 
    console.log('n1 é par');
} else {
  console.log('n1 é impar');
}
```

Com operador ternário, [mais informação na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operador_Condicional):

```
var n1 = 4;
(((n1 % 2) == 0) ? console.log('n1 é par') : console.log('n1 é impar'));
```

Comment: nossa, brigada moço <3

Comment: @MiyukiFukagawa se tiver como marca como a resposta correta ficarei grato \o/ ^^

Comment: nossa, eu entrei agora pra esse site e eu nao sei mexer em nada aqui, mas acho q eu marquei como resposta certa, mto obrigada novamentee <3